# Get the % of a number. PHP

Tags: php, math

Ok so I have these variables...

```
    $_SESSION['costTotal'] = $costTotal;
    $_SESSION['msTotal'] = $msTotal;
    $_SESSION['chargeTotal'] = $chargeTotal;
    $_SESSION['allowTotal'] = $allowTotal;
    $_SESSION['esProfit'] = $esProfit;
    $_SESSION['inPay'] = $insurancePer;
    $_SESSION['exIncome'] = $_SESSION['allowTotal'] * $_SESSION['inPay'];
    $_SESSION['abCost'] = ($_SESSION['allowTotal'] * $_SESSION['inPay']) * '0.05';
    $_SESSION['profit'] = $_SESSION['exIncome'] - ($costTotal + $_SESSION['abCost']);
    $_SESSION['proPerc'] = $_SESSION['profit'] / $allowTotal;
```

Ok, So Say my Profit is  `590.0052` and my AllowTotal is `2130.27`

Now I am going to print

```
$_SESSION['proPerc']
```

when I do that I get this number

```
0.27696263853878
```

I would like it to only show the numbers after the zero and round them..

so I want `0.27696263853878` to turn into `27.70%`

How can I format my code to achieve this?

Comment: Multiply by 100, and use [number_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or [sprint()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker  That works, but it is rounding it to 28.. Which is incorrect.. I only want it to round it to 27.70%

Comment: go for bcmul($_SESSION['proPerc'],100,2);

Comment: @narasimharaosp Thcomes very close but it still outputs 27.69 I need it to be 27.70

Comment: go for rounding then round(bcmul($_SESSION['proPerc'],100,2), 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN);

Comment: Perfect.. Just one more question... It's printing 27.7  I would like it to say 27.70 but if I use number_format(round(bcmul($_SESSION['proPerc'],100,2), 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN)); then it just rounds to 28 again. ... I know mathmatically 27.7 and 27.70 are the same thing. I would just like it to show 27.70 because its nicer looking. Also, Please Answer the question and I will accept it.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. Was obvious LOL THanks @narasimharaosp Please answer and I will accept your answer

Comment: as Mark Baker mentioned, `number_format(0.27696263853878 * 100, 2)` => 27.70

Comment: @Andrew Correct, He did not show me how to format it though. Which you did. Thanks. I have never used number_format so adding the 2 was unknown to me.

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 - that's where reading the PHP Documentation links that I posted in my comment would have helped you

Comment: @MarkBaker Your correct, Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you too @Mark Baker and @Andrew and @narasimharaosp

They all had the correct answers just put in different words.

```
number_format(0.27696263853878 * 100, 2)
```

Or use

```
round(bcmul($_SESSION['proPerc'],100,2), 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```

Thanks again guys.